# emit another state when load more data with flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, emit

How to implement load more data with flutter_bloc without reload every time: I have this:

post_bloc.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_events.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_repo.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_states.dart';

class PostsBloc extends Bloc<PostEvents, PostsStates> {
  PostRepo repo;

  int page = 1;

  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  PostsBloc(this.repo) : super(PostInitState()){
    on<FetchPosts>((event, emit) async{
        emit(PostLoadingState());
        final posts = await repo.fetchPosts(page);
        emit(PostLoadedState(posts: posts));
    });

    on<LoadMore>((event, emit) async{
      if (controller.position.pixels ==
          controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
       emit(LoadMoreState());
        page++;
        final posts = await repo.fetchPosts(page);
        emit(PostLoadedState(posts: posts));

      //  isLoadingMore = false;
      } else {
        print("not called");
      }
    });
  }


}
```

And at home.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_bloc.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_events.dart';
import 'package:scroool/post_states.dart';

class Scroool extends StatelessWidget {
  List posts = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocConsumer<PostsBloc, PostsStates>(
        listener: (context, state){},
        builder: (context, state) {
          if(state is PostLoadingState) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          } else if(state is PostLoadedState) {
            posts = posts + state.posts;
            return ListView.builder(
              controller: context.read<PostsBloc>().controller
                ..addListener(() => context.read<PostsBloc>().add(LoadMore())),
              itemCount: state is LoadMoreState
                  ? posts.length + 1 : posts.length ,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if(index < posts.length) {
                  final post = posts[index];
                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text("${index + 1}"),),
                        title: Text(post['author'].toString()),
                        subtitle: Text(post['title']['rendered']),
                      )
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                }
              },
            );

          } else {
            return Container();
          }

        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

It is working without any problem, but every time I need to load more is just re-emit the state and display data from beginning, I need just continue with more data not reload and add all data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your BLoC state so the parent state will have property `posts`. You can set it to empty list for states that do not use it.

```
abstract class PostState {
  final List<Post> posts;

  PostState(this.posts);
}

class PostLoadingState extends PostState {
  LoadMoreState() : super ([]);
}

class LoadMoreState extends PostState {
  LoadMoreState({required List<Post> posts}) : super (posts);
}

class PostLoadedState extends PostState {
  PostLoadedState({required List<Post> posts}) : super (posts);
}
```

Then change your BLoC accordingly:

```
on<LoadMore>((event, emit) async{
  if (controller.position.pixels ==
      controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
    emit(LoadMoreState(posts: state.posts));
    page++;
    final posts = await repo.fetchPosts(page);
    emit(PostLoadedState(posts: [...state.posts, ...posts]));
  } else {
    print("not called");
  }
});
```

In your widget remove the `posts` variable and use `posts` from bloc's state. Since your parent state has property `posts`, you can access `posts` for every state, including `LoadMoreState`. So change the if condition to return `ListView` for all states except `PostLoadingState`.

```
class Scroool extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: BlocConsumer<PostsBloc, PostsStates>(
          listener: (context, state){},
          builder: (context, state) {
            if(state is PostLoadingState) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            } else {
              final posts = state.posts;

              return ListView.builder(
                controller: context.read<PostsBloc>().controller
                  ..addListener(() => context.read<PostsBloc>().add(LoadMore())),
                itemCount: state is LoadMoreState
                    ? posts.length + 1 : posts.length ,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if(index < posts.length) {
                    final post = posts[index];
                    return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text("${index + 1}"),),
                          title: Text(post['author'].toString()),
                          subtitle: Text(post['title']['rendered']),
                        )
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                  }
                },
              );
            }
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i think it is almost worked, but I don't know how to add a loading indicator for loading more, and please can you explain why? I didn't change anything except just make the parent state have property posts

Comment: @OsamaMohammed I edited the answer to include widget code, also slightly edited `PostBloc` code as well. I cannot run the code and test it, so there might be bugs. Just understand the logic and make changes accordingly.

Comment: now, for (per page) parameter in endpoint I have added 20, but when I scroll for many times it is not looks like  add 20 each time and load again, but add more? why?

Comment: In `on<LoadMore>` add `state is! LoadMoreState` to the if-condition.

Comment: same problem, give me like double of items, instead of just add 20 each load

Comment: Try to debug, seems that `on<LoadMore>` is called more than needed. `context.read<PostsBloc>().controller..addListener(() => context.read<PostsBloc>().add(LoadMore()))` probably is adding a new listener every time. Convert your widget to `Stateful` and add listener only at `initState`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251243/discussion-between-osama-mohammed-and-kasymbek-r-tashbaev).